# router.navigate is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

bellow is my redirect method which is not working

```
    goToProdPage() {
       this.router.navigate([this.quoteId,'/cpq']);
       window.location.reload();
    }
```

but if i change this to

```
goToProdPage() {
     this.router.navigate(['./'+this.quoteId+'/cpq']);
     window.location.reload();
}
```

Then its working fine. but now i'm not able to get url param(which is quoteId) from activatedRoute in other components.

bellow is routing code in app.module.ts

```
const appRouter :Routes = [
   {path:'login', component: loginPage},
   {path:':quoteId/cpq', component: cpqPage},
   {path:'', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch:'full'},
]
```

Comment: why do you invoke window.location.reload?

Comment: And why are you building the string? The point of passing an array is that you can do things like `this.router.navigate([this.quoteId, 'cpq'])` and let the router worry about the details.

Comment: because before window.location.reload it was changing the url only not the content. so i forcefully reload the page so that i can go to the redirect loaction

Comment: @jonrsharpe but it is not working when i passing it as a array element . that is way i need ur help in this

Comment: Then **show that**, give a [mcve] that actually recreates the problem.

Comment: I would recommend https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need **`window.location.reload();`** which will  skip the cache and reload the same page, change it as

```
goToProdPage() {
    this.router.navigate([this.quoteId, 'cpq']);   
}
```